# Render scene shadows to texture (texture baking)

Tags: three.js

Does anyone know how to render a shadow map in threejs? I have a terrain mesh in my scene and instead of having all the objects cast a shadow on the terrain, I was hoping I could maybe render a nice shadow map to a texture that is applied to the mesh.

Does anyone have ideas of how to accomplish this - or perhaps some documentation on the subject that I could apply to three?

** EDIT **
Just to clarify for future references, I was wondering if there are any techniques available to render / bake textures that can later be applied as uniforms to a mesh.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at his example:
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_lightmap

What you are after are called "light maps" in threejs, in other places they are also referred to as oclusion textures/maps.

[Edit]
It is possible to bake a light-map from geometry using other tools, such as Blender: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13956/how-do-you-bake-ambient-occlusion-for-a-model

Comment: Hi travnik, actually I meant rendering a light map. So computing the shadows and drawing them to a texture (which then can be used in the terrain material). Similar to how Blender lets you render shadow maps onto the geometry (but thanks for the heads up :) )

Comment: @Mat sorry, but Three.js does not offer such functionality. It is possible to do this yourself. I did raytracing on terrain to get lightmap for it. Here's a link which has relevant information on this process:
http://codeflow.org/entries/2011/nov/10/webgl-gpu-landscaping-and-erosion/
Save that - you're probably limited to baking lights elsewhere and importing them into Three.js